# odoo12 reporting multi sections

Tags: report, odoo-12

i'm trying to print a report in odoo12, which displays multiple sections: in the sales module for example

Sale order form view has many tabs inside each tab a tree view.

my report must contain for each order line get all the associated BOM

Comment: Can you please show what exactly you've tried and visualize what you want, because with this question this is still unclear. If you can provide examples of input and expected output.

Comment: from the sale module -> sale order page
it has list of SOs inside the so form view has an order line and BOM order line tab
what i'm trying to do is to print a report displays all order lines and what materials should every order line has to have a final product X

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask next time you ask a question, because this one clearly does not satisfy